# What does "pending" mean after running rspec via rake?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to get this:

[http://www.amazon.com/Dream-Cheeky-902-Electronic-Reference/dp/B004D18MCK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004D18MCK)

working on a mac using this:

https://github.com/derrick/dream_cheeky

After running rake, it says "4 examples, 0 failures, 2 pending".  How do I execute the actual ruby example that I want?  (I'm a Ruby noob)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`4 examples, 0 failures, 2 pending` is a message from RSpec saying there are two unit tests that are **pending**.

A **pending** test is generally a test that the author hasn't fully implemented yet.  You can think of it like a function that you stubbed out to finish later.  For example:

```
def add_two_numbers(n1, n2)
  # TODO write some code that adds n1 and n2
end
```

As the comments mention, a pending test won't stop you from using the library successful.

Comment: I get the following under pending.  But under the system information, the USB device is found and displayed there.  Ideas?   `Pending:
  DreamCheeky::BigRedButton should raise an error when instantiated if it can't find a BigRedButton device
    # No reason given
    # ./spec/dream_cheeky/big_red_button_spec.rb:5
  DreamCheeky::UsbFidget should raise an error when instantiated if it can't find a UsbFidget device
    # No reason given
    # ./spec/dream_cheeky/usb_fidget_spec.rb:5`

Comment: Zach, that message doesn't mean something is wrong with your system or with rake. It means that those unit tests, which are specific to dream_cheeky, are pending. This doesn't mean the app won't work, necessarily.

Comment: @ZachLucas If my answer helped you out, I would greatly appreciate an upvote or a checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of pending:

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/pending/pending-examples